# uneven quickfix window output from Ack/Ag

Tags: quickfix

For some reason I get, what I call an "uneven" output from Ack/Ag in the quickfix list window.

My project directory structure is the following:

```
/home/user/projects/myproject
 |
 ---- llvm-or1k
 |
 ---- clang-or1k
```

I did a search with Ag using the following command:

```
:ag --nogroup --nocolor --column -S -U BuildSchedGraph /home/user/projects/myproject
```

And got the following output (snippet)

```
...

/home/user/projects/myproject/llvm-or1k/lib/CodeGen/SelectionDAG/ScheduleDAGSDNodes.h|176 col 63| /// BuildSchedUnits, AddSchedEdges - Helper functions for BuildSchedGraph.

llvm-or1k/lib/CodeGen/SelectionDAG/ScheduleDAGVLIW.cpp|100 col 3| BuildSchedGraph(AA);

/home/user/projects/myproject/llvm-or1k/lib/CodeGen/SelectionDAG/ScheduleDAGRRList.cpp|336 col 3| BuildSchedGraph(NULL);

...
```

I can't understand why the first and the last "finds" have `/home/user/projects/myproject` prepended to the path while the second one doesn't.

This is becoming quite annoying.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is annoying.

When Vim creates a quickfix list from the output of a program such as Ack, it creates a buffer for each file in the quickfix list using the name provided by the other program. This is often a full path name. Vim simplifies or resolves those names to relative path names upon certain events. The problem is that those names are not resolved when the quickfix list is displayed, so you see a mixture of full path names and relative path names.

There is no good solution available to users.

I have a workaround that is very much a hack, but it works for me because of the way I use Vim. That is, when I'm working on a project for which I use quickfix lists generated from programs such as cscope, I always start Vim in the top-level directory of the project and never use `:cd` or `:lcd`. It turns out that executing `:cd` is one of the events that causes Vim to resolve its buffer names, so I have the following in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
au BufAdd * exe "cd" fnameescape(getcwd())
```

As Vim creates the quickfix list, it adds a buffer for each file. That autocommand executes `:cd` to the current working directory for each file added and causes the file names to be resolved. Executing `:cd` like that is a no-op in my case. Again, this is a hack and it has side effects depending on what you're doing, but it works for me in my situation and makes my quickfix lists more appealing. It may work for you, too.

Comment: Actually it _could_ be fixed, by post-processing the output of `ack` / `ag` to call `fnamemodify(file, ':~:.')` on all filenames before feeding it back to be parsed with `errorformat`.  This would involve replacing `makeprg` and `make` (or `Make` from `dispatch`) with `system()` and `cgetexpr`.  Not really a complicated change, but it would involve a change in the philosophical approach to the problem. :)

Comment: @garyjohn Just to make it clear for myself. I see a mixture of output because in some cases there is a certain event happening and after the event Vim resolves the path to relative. In those cases when it doesn't happen the path stays the the same. Am I correct?

Comment: @lcd047 Will you be able to guide me through the process of using your approach, i.e `fnamemodify(file, ':~:.')`, etc. I know asking to help on this is a long shot but I've never done anything like this before and would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: @flashburn: What I observed was that when I had visited a file, so that it was in my buffer list (`:ls`), it would have a relative path name. Any quickfix "hits" to files already in my buffer list would appear in the quickfix list with the names used for the buffers, i.e., relative path names. Any quickfix "hits" to files not in the buffer list would be added to the buffer list (visible using `:ls!`; note the `!`) with the names as given by the program creating the list, usually full path names. So the initial difference in appearance was due to whether or not I had already opened the file.

Comment: @garyjohn There seems to be an issue already open with the Ack developer. Someone made a [post](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim/issues/143#issuecomment-109558188) about this. They also offered a [solution](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim/blob/f04a8a9af3854f9fd97318e05a0e5e05281da33f/autoload/ack.vim#L77). It looks like it is already implemented in Ack but I wonder why it doesn't work.

Comment: @flashburn: I don't know why it doesn't seem to work. I don't have Ack installed so I can't easily check it out. You could sprinkle some `:echomsg` commands in ack.vim and look in the message history to see what's happening. Or, you could use Vim's debug features (`:help debug-scripts`).

Comment: @garyjohn What do you use instead of Ack? Maybe I can switch and use what you use.

Comment: I use `find`, `ctags`, `gtags` and `grep`. I use `find` in a script with some other filters to build lists of files for `ctags` and `gtags`, then run those programs to build their indexes. The `ctags` index is sorted so that Vim can use a fast binary search. I use `gtags-cscope` as a better `cscope`. I use a Vim script to make an easier interface to Vim's `cscope` commands. I haven't seen any advantage to using `ack` instead of `grep`. When I'm not looking for a symbol with `ctags` or `gtags`, I usually want to search _every_ file in the project. Otherwise, I use `grep`'s `--include=` option.

Comment: @garyjohn Wow!!! You must be really good at using Vim. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @garyjohn Do you use gtags-csope with C++ or C code? How do you generate and connect a gtags-cscope database to Vim? I'd would really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29500/discussion-between-garyjohn-and-flashburn).

Answer (score 0):

As garyjohn pointed out:

> It turns out that executing :cd is one of the events that causes Vim to resolve its buffer names.

So you can use that in a simple command:

```
command! Copen cd / | copen
```

You may want to cd to a more useful directory.

You could make this automatic with QuickFixCmdPost. See `:h QuickFixCmdPost-example`:

```
au QuickfixCmdPost make cd /home/user/projects/myproject | copen
```

or with garyjohn's no-op method:

```
au QuickfixCmdPost make exe "cd" fnameescape(getcwd())
```

But using cwd means some paths will be relative and some absolute. Using the project root makes them all relative.